# Markers Too Dark with Plotly Scatter3d

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-python

I am making some scatter plots with plotly and setting the marker colors manually. With a 2d scatter plot (graph_objects.Scatter) everything works as expected. With 3d though (graph_objects.Scatter3d) the legend is correct but the markers on the plots are way too dark (often just black). The following code

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

fig = make_subplots()
fig.update_layout(height=600, width=1200)
x , y, z = np.linspace(0, 100, 100), np.linspace(-10, 10, 100), np.linspace(5, 25, 100)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=x, y=y, z=z, mode='markers', marker={'color': 'rgb(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)'}, name='Red'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=x+100, y=y, z=z, mode='markers', marker={'color': 'rgb(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)'}, name='Blue'))
fig.show()
```

Produces two lines of black markers. [image: 3D Plot w/ Dark Markers]

Does anyone know what causes this? I thought maybe the marker dict isn't the same for Scatter3d but looking at the docs I think it is plus the legend shows the colors correctly.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this.  Looks like it might be an outstanding bug according to a [similar issue on GitHub](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/4942)?  I'd say you're safest just using the 0-255 integer scale if possible.

Comment: That did indeed work. Should have tried that but I thought it was understanding the color because the legend showed up correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per @frodnar comment,  using 255 instead of 1.0 does work

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

x, y, z = np.linspace(0, 100, 100), np.linspace(-10, 10, 100), np.linspace(5, 25, 100)

for c in ["1.0", "255"]:
    go.Figure(
        [
            go.Scatter3d(
                x=x,
                y=y,
                z=z,
                mode="markers",
                marker={"color": f"rgb({c}, 0.0, 0.0)"},
                name="Red",
            ),
            go.Scatter3d(
                x=x + 100,
                y=y,
                z=z,
                mode="markers",
                marker={"color": f"rgb(0.0, 0.0, {c})"},
                name="Blue",
            ),
        ],
        layout={"title": f"color {c}"},
    ).show()
```